# Mostrar ciertos datos de una columna

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo mi siguiente tabla llamada LISTA con dos columnas: Id, y Nombre, en la columna Nombre tengo 4 datos: Notas, Agenda, Autorización y Membresia.

```
 public IQueryable Listar1()
    {

        return from titus1 in Contexto.LISTA



               select new
               {
                   titus1.Nombre

               };
    }
```

Pero solo quiero mostrar los datos de Agenda y Membresia, de la columna Nombre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres obtener los dos registros que tienen esos datos puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
return from titus1 in Contexto.LISTA
       where titus1.Nombre == "Agenda" || titus.Nombre == "Membresia"
           select new
           {
               titus1.Nombre

           };
```

o de la forma "funcional" (la dejo como opción):

```
return Contexto.LISTA
    .Where(x => x.Nombre == "Agenda" || x.Nombre == "Membresia")
    .Select(new { titus1.Nombre});
```

Ahora, si solo quieres el dato que tiene la columna nombre, yo lo dejaría así:

```
return from titus1 in Contexto.LISTA
       where titus1.Nombre == "Agenda" || titus.Nombre == "Membresia"
           select titus.Nombre;
```

Eso te regresaría únicamente el contenido del campo Nombre, básicamente una lista de tipo string con dos elementos. Ya depende de cómo quieras utilizar los datos de la query.